# Bad value google for attribute name on element meta

Tags: html, meta-tags

Is there an alternative for HTML5 for google notranslate meta tag. I getting the error below when validating HTML5.

`Bad value google for attribute name on element meta: Keyword google is not registered.
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />`

Comment: That looks like a failing of the validator. That tag should pass HTML5 validation right now, but only since 21st August. The validator has clearly not caught up yet. Have you tried putting `class="notranslate"` on the `<html>` tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The keyword `google` is registered at http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions:

> A content of `notranslate` will tell google not to pop up the
>   translate bar / link if the page is in a foreign language form the
>   user's browser.
>
> `<meta name="google" content="notranslate">`

So [it is valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#other-metadata-names) to use this keyword in HTML5. If a validator reports this as an error, the validator is probably not up to date or simply wrong.