# W3C validator: "Bad value robots for attribute name on element meta"

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta, w3c-validation

What has changed with `<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">` meta tag? I use HTML5 and W3C validator marks my page as invalid. There is `robots` meta name allowed in http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions.

Exact validator error:

> Bad value `robots` for attribute `name` on element `meta`: Keyword `robots` is not registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validator is wrong.

The `robots` name is [registered](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions) according to [HTML5’s rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names), so you can use it.

You’ll probably see the same problem with all other registered names, too (e.g., with the [`google` name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12861069/1591669)).