# How to handle multiple values in meta robots?

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags, bots, search-engine-bots

About the `meta`-`robots`, how many values can I put?

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow, nocache, nosnippet, noodp, noydir">
```

Is this valid? Or multiple meta elements?

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
<meta name="robots" content="nocache, nosnippet">
<meta name="robots" content="noodp, noydir">
```

Is this possible?

What is the best practice?

Comment: You can combine them with commas, it is valid. I am not sure but `contents` must be `content`

Comment: @HddnTHA thanks :D
about content, you're right, I'm tired ...

Comment: your welcome. Take a cup of coffee and relax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question's first code block;

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow, nocache, nosnippet, noodp, noydir">
```

It is valid. You can combine them with commas use it in under 1 tag. 

You can also find some good examples in this **[link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/meta#Example_A)**

Answer (score 2):

For HTML5, the `robots` name is [registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22134218/1591669) in WHATWG‘s [MetaExtensions](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions). There it says:

> A comma-separated list of operators explaining how search engine crawlers should treat the content.

But as the entry in the wiki doesn‘t define that it’s restricted to one occurrence (like it’s the case with `meta`-`description`), it [should be valid to have several](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54979/17633) `meta`-`robots` elements in a document.

If you don’t have a good reason to use several elements, use only one and comma-separate its values.